# Want to remove Unexpected object like "headers","original","exception" from Laravel JSON output

Tags: json, laravel

I am getting JSON response like this. But I want to remove "headers", "original" and "exception".

```
    {
         "headers": {},
         "original": [        

             {
                 "id": 271,
                 "name": "TestController",
                 "parent_id": null

             }
         ],
         "exception": null
   }
```

Output expected:

```
{
    "data": {
      "id": 271,
      "name": "TestController",
      "parent_id": null
    },
    "errors": [],
    "success": true,
    "status_code": 200
}
```

Comment: where the data coming. I mean it is from third party API?

Comment: No. I have created API and want to return response. But this additional information is generating. I am using "jwt-auth" package for token-based authentication.

Answer (score 5):

You are returning a `response()->json()` inside another `response()->json()` something along the way:

```
response()->json(response()->json($data,200),200)
```

or more like:

```
$data = [
  "id"=> 271,
  "name"=> "TestController",
  "parent_id"=> null
];

$response = response()->json($data,200);

return response()->json($response ,200);
```

You may not have notice it because of a function returning the first `response()->json()` into the second one

Answer (score 2):

The issue is triggered because you are returning nested responses somewhere in your code.

Here is a simple code that demonstrates the issue and the fix.

```
// A normal function that you think it returns an array
// but instead, it is returning a response object!
public function get_data(){

    //ISSUE
    return response([1, 2, 3]); // <- this will trigger the issue becuase
                                // it returns the data as a response not an array

    //FIX
    return [1, 2, 3]; // <- this will work as intended 
                      // bacause the data is returned as a normal array
}

public function get_all_data(){
    $first_array = [1, 2];
    $second_array = [2, 3];
    $third_array = get_data(); // <- here is the call to the function
                               // that should return an array
    
    //Return the JSON response
    return response([first_array, second_array, third_array]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did, and it worked for me:
just call the original object after getting your response like this:

```
public function user_object(){

  return $this->me()->original;
  
}
```

This is the me() function that returns user details

```
public function me()
{
    return response()->json(auth('users')->user()->only(['id','name','email','status','phonenumber','type']));
}
```

This is my response from post man:

```
{
"success": true,
"user": {
    "id": 29,
    "name": "test6",
    "email": "test6@gmail.com",
    "status": 1,
    "phonenumber": "413678675",
    "type": "user"
},
"token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOlwvXC8xMjcuMC4wLjE6ODAwMFwvYXBpXC9hdXRoXC9yZWdpc3RlciIsImlhdCI6MTU5OTQ3MDc3OCwiZXhwIjoxNTk5NDc0Mzc4LCJuYmYiOjE1OTk0NzA3NzgsImp0aSI6InFyUWEyTVNLVzR4a2o0ZVgiLCJzdWIiOjI5LCJwcnYiOiI4N2UwYWYxZWY5ZmQxNTgxMmZkZWM5NzE1M2ExNGUwYjA0NzU0NmFhIn0.SMHgYkz4B4BSn-fvUqJGfsgqHc_r0kMDqK1-y9-wLZI",
"expires_in": 3600
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
$json='{
     "headers": {},
     "original": [        

         {
             "id": 271,
             "name": "TestController",
             "parent_id": null

         }
     ],
     "exception": null
}';

$arr=json_decode($json);
$data=$arr->original[0];

$new_json=array();
$new_json['data']=$data;
$new_json['errors']=[];
$new_json['success']=true;
$new_json['status_code']=200;

$new_json=json_encode($new_json);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. But problem not solved yet.

Comment: in my case, I forgot to use response()->json() to send data from a method, while the method itself is already use response()->json()

Answer (score 0):

You may have doubled the data json return with `response()->json()`

you can use array only

```
return ["data"=> [
  "id"=> 271,
  "name"=> "TestController",
  "parent_id"=> null
],
"errors"=> [],
"success"=> true,
"status_code"=> 200
];
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case this problem solved with this solution:

You can use:

```
return json_decode(json_encode($ResponseData), true);
```

And return response